# Can not see the credentials when I installed jira plugin on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have installed Jenkins on my laptop and installed Jira-plugin on jenkins. To test Jira plugin, I need to configure Jira.

the image of my config:
[image: (the image of my config)]
But I can not see the credentials for Jira when I follow the [doc](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin)

image of the document:
[image: (the image of the document)]

Following the document, the credentials that I have to use in cloud : username and password.

So, Is there something wrong? what is failing?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is outdated. Username and password has been replaced with Credentials plugin in version 3.0.1 ([JENKINS-45789](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45789)).